# Legitimate technique for avoiding file download blocker in IE ("To help protect your security")?

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer

My web app allows export of data in a variety of formats. The export is triggered by selecting an export format from a dropdown (`<select>`), which causes the form to be POSTed and the file returned and downloaded in the requested export format.

This works fine on all browsers except for IE - on IE the "To help protect your security" blocker appears, and clicking on the "Click here for options" causes the page to reload instead of allowing the actual download.

In short IE users can't download files due to the blocker and the subsequent reload instead of download.

I know we can ask users to change their security zone settings to enable download, but for a variety of reasons this is not practical - there are a lot of users in a lot of different environments and they tend to ignore instructions.

Are the rules for what causes the blocker to come up documented somewhere? What's the legitimate, recommended way of allowing file downloads in IE? That is, for the scenario detailed below, how can I setup the HTML/form to actually let the user download the file?

- Show the user a list of file formats
- Once the user selects a file, download it to her computer without triggering the download blocker on IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your `<select>` block simply inject (using JavaScript) `<a href="url_to_actual_format"> click here to download </a>` text somewhere else in the DOM tree. Then, the user clicks on a standard link and it reloads the full page, downloading the file directly.

You can even have the `<a href="url?format=blah"> click </a>` to cause GET requests..

Comment: Thanks qdot, looks like I may have to detect IE and instead of posting the form showing the user a direct link to click on. Will try it and update.

Comment: I've seen sites swap out the selector for the direct link with javascript.. looks rather nice.